# synchronous exception handling in Python

Tags: python, exception

I have following code:

```
try:
    print('a')
    ... something to rise exception, in my case call to DB
except:
    print('c')
```

when running this code twice fast enough, I get following:

```
a
a
c
c
```

looks like exception handling is asynchronous. Is it possible to force it synchronous?

Comment: Exception handling is "synchronous".  I believe you have misinterpreted the data.  Does "twice fast enough" mean that you ran a program from the shell multiple times without waiting for the prior executions to complete?

Comment: in my case those are two calls from frontend to a web server. It might be somthing to do with server or framework maybe. I am using pyramid and pserve.

Comment: How did we get here?  Why are you concerned about the behavior of exception handling?  Do you need to synchronize the exception handler activity among requests?

Comment: Is it possible the server is multi-threaded, so your two requests were being executed concurrently?

Comment: I think if Brian is right that exceptions are synchronous then probably Dano is right as well. And yes I need to synchronise exceptions.

Comment: In that case you should consider [multiprocessing.Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock).

Comment: thanks, looks like locking can help ... will explore that ...